# Overload resolution between constructor and inherited constructor in C++ - which compiler is correct?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

In the following program `struct B` inherits `B(int)` deleted constructor from its base `A`, and also defines additional constructor `B(int&&)`. Then an object of `B` is created with `B b(1)`:

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    A(int) = delete;
};

struct B : A {
    using A::A;
    B(int&&) {}
};

int main() {
    B b(1);
}
```

If both constructors `B(int)` and `B(int&&)` had been defined directly in `B` the result would have been the ambiguity of constructor selection. And in this example, GCC prints a

> call of overloaded 'B(int)' is ambiguous`

error as well.

But Clang prefers the constructor declared in `B` over the one inherited from `A`. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dnErEenE5

Which compiler is right here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GCC** is correct here: there is a tiebreaker that prefers direct over inherited constructors ([over.match.best.general]/2.7), but it applies only if they have the same parameter types (ignoring those whose default arguments are being used).